# Calculadora interactiva

Tags: python, calculo

Estoy tratando de hacer una especie de calculador muy básica, con las operaciones ("+" "-" "*" "//"),
pero quiero que la calculadora pueda interactúar con el usuario, haciendo preguntas sobre qué tipo de operación desea realizar y etc, y a partir de ahí ejecutar las operaciones. Lo que logré hasta ahora no da error pero no funciona debidamente.

```
print("Ingresa el primer valor")

num1 = int(input())

print(" ")

print("¿Qué tipo de operación desea realizar?")

input()

if input("//"):

 print("Divivsión")
if input("*" ):

 print("Multiplicación")
if input("+"):  

print("Suma")
if input("-" ):

print("Resta")
operador = input()

print("Ingresa el segundo valor")

num2 = int(input())

resultado = num1 num2

print(resultado)
```

Comment: ':D Gracias, soy nuevo en todo eso, pero seguro que con la ayuda de la comunidad y buenos consejos iré atinando. Gracias  :D

Comment: Por supuesto, no te preocupes, si te atascas con algo relacionado con el formateo o tienes alguna duda relacionada con el sitio simplemente dejalo como puedas y comentalo, seguro que alguien te puede ayudar. Por cierto,  bienvenido a [es.so] :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por todo :D Me será muy útil ;)

Comment: Interesante, lo miraré :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por partes:

- La linea `input()` no hace absolutamente nada, aparte de esperar que el usuario ingrese <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Cualquier cosa que ingrese al no asociar la salida de la función a una variable no es utilizable y es eliminada inmediatamente por el GC.
- Los condicionales tampoco hacen lo que esperas. Por ejemplo:

  ```
  if input("*" )
  ```

  lo que hace es ejecutar `input`, ésta espera a que el usuario ingrese algo y pulse <kbd>Enter</kbd>. La cadena retornada se evalúa como verdadera o falsa, lo cual significa que si ingresó algo (una cadena no vacía) será verdadera y si solo pulsó <kbd>Enter</kbd> será falsa. Esto se repite con el resto de condicionales.

  En ningún momento `input` comprueba que se ingresó `"*"` y retorna `True` o `False` en base a ello.

  Ten en cuenta que el argumento que recibe `input` es una cadena que sirve para **imprimirla por la salida estándar cuando se pide la entrada**. De hecho, en vez de usar `print` y luego `input`, puedes y debes pasar la cadena a `input` directamente.

  Por otro lado, `input` siempre retorna la cadena ingresada, tipo `str`, sin más.
- Debes usar una estructura `if-elif` y no `if` encadenados. Si usas `if` encadenados se evaluarán todos aunque uno sea cierto y eso no lo quieres.

Podrías hacer algo como:

```
num1 = int(input("Ingresa el primer valor\n"))
operación = input("\n¿Qué tipo de operación desea realizar?\n")

if operación == "/": 
     print("División")
     num2 = int(input("Ingresa el segundo valor\n"))
     resultado = num1 / num2 
     print(resultado)

elif operación == "*" :
     print("Multiplicación")
     num2 = int(input("Ingresa el segundo valor\n"))
     resultado = num1 * num2 
     print(resultado)

elif operación == "+": 
    print("Suma")
    num2 = int(input("Ingresa el segundo valor\n"))
    resultado = num1 + num2 
    print(resultado)

elif operación == "-": 
    print("Resta")
    num2 = int(input("Ingresa el segundo valor\n"))
    resultado = num1 - num2 
    print(resultado)

else:
    print("Operación no disponible")
```

El código se puede reducir sin modificar la lógica y el orden usando funciones por ejemplo, pero para no liar más lo dejo así.

Comment: Muchas gracia maquina :)